# SQL*Loader - How can i ignore certain rows with a specific charactre

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

If i have a CSV file that is in the following format

```
"fd!","sdf","dsfds","dsfd"
"fd!","asdf","dsfds","dsfd"
"fd","sdf","rdsfds","dsfd"
"fdd!","sdf","dsfds","fdsfd"
"fd!","sdf","dsfds","dsfd"
"fd","sdf","tdsfds","dsfd"
"fd!","sdf","dsfds","dsfd"
```

Is it possible to exclude any row where the first column has an exclamation mark at the end of the string.
i.e. it should only load the following rows

```
"fd","sdf","rdsfds","dsfd"
"fd","sdf","tdsfds","dsfd"
```

Thanks

Comment: which version of Oracle DB your have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Loading Records Based on a Condition](http://www.comp.dit.ie/btierney/oracle11gdoc/server.111/b28319/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657) section of the SQL*Loader Control File Reference (11g):

*"You can choose to load or discard a logical record by using the **WHEN** clause to test a condition in the record."*

So you'd need something like this:

```
LOAD DATA ... INSERT INTO TABLE mytable   WHEN mycol1 NOT LIKE '%!' 
(mycol1..  ,mycol2 ..)
```

But the **LIKE** operator is not available! You only have  **=** and **!=**

Maybe you could try an External Table instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick a CONSTRAINT on the table, and just let them be rejected. Maybe delete them after load. Or a unix "grep -v" to clear them out the file.