# SQLloader to skip particular pattern

Tags: sql-loader

how do I skip row with particular pattern in slqloader?

data is like

```
A
B
C
D
```

and I want A C D to be loaded.

anyone can help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL\*Loader - How can i ignore certain rows with a specific charactre](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419182/sqlloader-how-can-i-ignore-certain-rows-with-a-specific-charactre)

Comment: Ya, I've tried that before, the sqlloader will discard row that are not in the when clause in default, using the link's method, it can discard the record as well, but the concurrent program of the sqlloader will in warning status, how do I return normal status even there is discarded record?

Answer (score 1):

Write a program or wrapper script around the call to SQL-loader that strips out those lines before loading via SQL-Loader.